# Printing last 5 digits in C (Octal base)

Tags: c, printf, octal

I was wondering how could I print just the last 5 digits of an octal number in C programming language?

Tricky part: the number is unsigned in definition, so after some procedures it outputs something like 3777777464. What I want to print is just 77464.

I tried to look around in C formatting guides, but I only found out how to write the first 5 digits/characters, not the last 5 ones in regards to the tricky part mentioned.

It is only needed to be displayed in output (printf/fprintf in a file).

EDIT and emphasize: The code is too long to post here, It consists of many c files and headers. To make it concise: I need printf("%05o\n",arr[i]); to print only last 5 digits. It prints something like 3777777464. The numbers are correct, I just need the last 5 digits

Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: "after some procedures it outputs something like 3777777464" --> post that code.

Comment: what procedures?

Comment: the code is too long to post here, it consists of many c files and headers. to make it concise: i need printf("%05o\n",arr[i]); to print only last 5 digits. it prints something like 3777777464. the numbers are correct, i just need the last 5 digits

Comment: So use the code chux presented. Did you use it? What did it result in? Were you satisfied with the result? Doesn't it answer your question? `i need printf("%05o\n",arr[i]);` - what is `arr`? what is `i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> print just the last 5 (octal) digits of a number

Derive the last 5 octal digits by anding with a mask of the 077777.

```
#define MASK_LAST_5_OCTAL_DIGITS 077777u

//       vv print at least 5 characters, pad with 0 as needed 
printf("%05o\n", (unsigned) (number & MASK_LAST_5_OCTAL_DIGITS));
```

Comment: Could you please look at the updated question? it would help a lot if you could help overcome this

Comment: because of unsigned int conversion, i get something like 3777777 even after the %05o formatting.

Comment: @newB Really need to see your code.